# Does setInterval in node.js start running when computer falls asleep?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, setinterval

I'm trying to fetch an API in node.js **server** and updated the stored data by using setInterval in JavaScript in every 3 hours. The code is like this: (I'm using mongoDB as database)

```
mongoose.connect(
  constants.db,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    reconnectTries: 30000,
  },
  () => {
    app.listen(5000, () => {
      console.log("server is running");
      const time = 10800000; // for 3 hours
      setInterval(dataFetch, time);
      dataFetch();
    });
  }
);
```

The problem is that I want to use heroku free web-hosting plan and as you know, in this case, heroku make the server sleep after 1 hour until it receives a request and I want to make sure that in case of server sleep, this code do the job well.

Please guide me to handle this case of situation. Thank you :)

Comment: Why not make periodical requests on your server from itself ? to keep it up

Comment: @Ezzat heroku only make 550 hours in month for free and by this way I will lose this available time. I want to use it all days in a month :)

Comment: The fetching process takes between 40-60 minutes ( I get huge amount of data )

Comment: Check out [1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) and [2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-redis-workers)

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you. I'm going to try it.

Comment: Hi guys.
I finally found that heroku only cost on its dynoes which response to the specific direct request. Case that I want to do some 'background-work', because it's not designed for sending response, the `dataFetch()` can place in ***worker*** dyno that doesn't have any limitation for execution.

for more information, please check above links that @ggorlen mentioned on this question.

Comment: Feel free to post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your solution!